# Store multiple values in excel based on search criteria

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

I am getting emp id from the database through query and storing the emp id in an excel sheet.for example storing 10 emp ids in an excel named as empid details. and after get one by one emp id from excel and search in application , we get employee invoice numbers list and need to store those invoice numbers list in the first column and related emp Id in 2nd column in another excel named as invoice details.only first 10 invoice numbers list we need to store in excel. 
I have done my coding part for storing single emp Id invoice details. Can anyone help me how to achieve code for n Num of emp Id and storing their invoices with emp id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the more info like what have you coded so far and where you are finding the difficulty with some pictures or code

Comment: As you mentioned, you have done coding for storing the single(first) emp Id invoice details - Like in the same way, try to do looping up to n number of times by increasing the rows index.

Comment: I can put invoice numbers in loop to store for all emp ids. But my prob is how to store the emp Id with invoice numbers in the invoice numbers excel sheet.

Comment: Post the code you have tried and the result.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the Excel file name, Sheet name, Row number, Column number and Storing values as per your requirement and follow the comments for an explanation.

Try the below code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class Answer {
    // Below method will give the excel data based on the passed row and the column number
    private static String getData(String fileName, String sheetName, int rowNumber, int columnNumber) throws Exception {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
        return row.getCell(columnNumber).getStringCellValue().trim();
    }
    // Below method will return the row count
    private static int getRowCount(String fileName, String sheetName) throws Exception {
        return WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName)).getSheet(sheetName).getLastRowNum() + 1;
    }
    // Below method will store the data in excel sheet based on the passed row and column indexes
    private static void putData(String fileName, String sheetName, int rowNumber, int columnNumber, String cellValue) throws Exception {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
        row.createCell(columnNumber).setCellValue(cellValue);
    }
    public static void main(String ...ali) throws Exception {
        // Retrieve data from the Database using some queries

        // Store the retrieved data into some excel sheet

        // After doing the above two steps, below code will retrieve previously stored emp id's and will store into an other excel sheet
        // Pass the corresponding absolute excel file path with name, sheet names in the below sample code 

        for(int i=0;i<getRowCount("SomeExcelFileName", "SomeExcelSheetName");i++) {
            // Get one by one emp id from excel
            String empID = getData("SomeExcelFileName", "SomeExcelSheetName", i, 0);

            // Search in the application and get invoice numbers list and store it
            List<String> invoiceDetails = null;

            // Store the invoice details list in the first column, here the row number is starting from 1 and column index is 0
            putData("AntoherExcelFile", "AnotherExcelSheet", (i+1), 0, invoiceDetails.toString());

            // Store the related emp id in the second column, here the row number is starting from 1 and column index is 1
            putData("AntoherExcelFile", "AnotherExcelSheet", (i+1), 1, empID);
        }
    }
}
```

If the program gets executed successfully without any errors then you will have the data in excel in the below sample format:

```
|Invoice Details | Emp ID|
| details 1      | 3333  |
| some details   | 1306  |
| Hello World!   | 2019  |
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: my req is quite diffrent one. i cant use Row to create rows. it is jxl.

Comment: Ok, you are using the third party library called `JavaExcelAPI` for fetching the data. But JXL supports only .xls file format and it cannot handle large data volume, I recommend you to use Apache POI because it supports many and easy to use.

Comment: Are you telling that my code also wrong? Because you are using some other tools and through apache poi you didn't meet your requirement? If the code is or the requirement is correct but you want using the jxl only then I can try that too...

Comment: i didnt mean that your code is wrong. i cant apply that in my code . Below is my code. Please help how do i store for all emp ids first 10 invoice numbers? public void connectToDatabaseAndGetData() throws Exception{
     Connection con = null;
//providing driver class here
  Class.forName("driver name").newInstance();
//providing db url, un,pwd
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("URL", "UN", "PWD");
  System.out.println("Connection Created");
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try{
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   System.out.println("Statement Created");

Comment: System.out.println("Query executed");
   ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
  
   
   
  }catch (Exception e) {
   
   System.out.println("Error.......: "+e);
  }

Comment: Sure, I will try to help. But I have some doubts, the code which you have posted above is related to database right?

Comment: But you want to know how to store data into excel as two separate columns corresponding invoice details equals emp id right?

Comment: You can go through my code which i have posted. by seeing that where i have stucked you will come to know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick responses@ Ali cse

Comment: @user10983725, I have added the modified answer. Try it and let me know it is helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I changed the code from Apache POI to Java Excel API for retrieving and storing the data from an excel.

Try the below code and let me know if you are facing any issues...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.CellView;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.format.UnderlineStyle;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableFont;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;

public class OneMore {
    private WritableCellFormat timesBoldUnderline;
    private WritableCellFormat times;
    private WritableWorkbook workbook;
    private WritableSheet excelSheet;
    private String inputFile;
    private List<String> empIDs, invoiceDetails;

    public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void write(int SheetNumber) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        workbook.createSheet("Required", SheetNumber);
        excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(SheetNumber);
        createLabel(excelSheet);
    }

    private void createLabel(WritableSheet sheet) throws Exception {
        // Lets create a times font
        WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10);
        // Define the cell format
        times = new WritableCellFormat(times10pt);
        // Lets automatically wrap the cells
        times.setWrap(true);

        // create create a bold font with unterlines
        WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false, UnderlineStyle.SINGLE);
        timesBoldUnderline = new WritableCellFormat(times10ptBoldUnderline);
        // Lets automatically wrap the cells
        timesBoldUnderline.setWrap(true);

        CellView cv = new CellView();
        cv.setFormat(times);
        cv.setFormat(timesBoldUnderline);
        cv.setAutosize(true);

        // Write a few headers
        addCaption(sheet, 0, 0, "Invoice Details");
        addCaption(sheet, 1, 0, "Emp ID");
    }

    private void retrieveDataFromDBAndStoreItInExcel(WritableSheet sheet) throws Exception {
        // Handling data base part
        Connection con = null;
        Class.forName("driver name").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("URL", "UN", "PWD");
        System.out.println("Connection Created");
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Statement Created");
            String query = "query to get data from db";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Query executed");
            ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error.......: "+e);
        }

        // Storing the database data into the excel
        for(int i=0; rs.next();i++) {
            // First column
            addLabel(sheet, 0, i, rs.getString(1));
        }
        rs.close();
    }

    private void createContent(List<String> list, WritableSheet sheet, int columnNumber) throws Exception {
        for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {
            // First column
            addLabel(sheet, columnNumber, i, list.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    private void addCaption(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s) throws Exception {
        Label label;
        label = new Label(column, row, s, timesBoldUnderline);
        sheet.addCell(label);
    }

    private void addLabel(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s) throws Exception {
        Label label;
        label = new Label(column, row, s, times);
        sheet.addCell(label);
    }

    public void read() throws Exception  {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        empIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
        Workbook w;
        try {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            // Loop over first column up to 10 rows
            for(int i=0;i<sheet.getRows();i++) {
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell(0, i);
                CellType type = cell.getType();
                if (type == CellType.LABEL) {
                    empIDs.add(cell.getContents());
                }
            }
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OneMore test = new OneMore();
        // Retrieving Data from the Database and storing in the First Excel
        test.setOutputFile("C:\\NotBackedUp\\OxygenWorkspace\\HelloSelenium\\src\\main\\resources\\test\\FirstExcel.xls");
        test.write(0);
        test.retrieveDataFromDBAndStoreItInExcel(test.excelSheet);
        test.workbook.write();
        test.workbook.close();
        System.out.println("=> The First Excel Writing task completed...");

        // Reading data from the First Excel and storing it in empIDs ArrayList
        test.read();
        System.out.println("=> The Excel Data is : "+test.empIDs);

        // You use empIDs ArrayList which has emp ids for getting the invoice details from the Application and store it in the invoiceDetails ArrayList below
        test.invoiceDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
        test.invoiceDetails.add("Invoice Details from the Application");

        // Writing the Invoice Details and the emp id Data to the Second Excel
        test.setOutputFile("C:\\NotBackedUp\\OxygenWorkspace\\HelloSelenium\\src\\main\\resources\\test\\SecondExcel.xls");
        test.write(0);
        test.createContent(test.invoiceDetails, test.excelSheet, 0);
        test.createContent(test.empIDs, test.excelSheet, 1);
        test.workbook.write();
        test.workbook.close();
    }
}
```

I have tried using the jxl for the first time so I have tested reading and writing the data to the excel in my system and working as expected.

But I haven't tested the database part and all, so try to modify/execute by following comments in the main() method. You don't need to code anything, just you need to change some configuration details and the excel file name paths as per your requirements.

I hope it helps... Happy Coding...